# PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey() difference on Windows

Tags: c++, openssl, cross-platform, rsa, pem

I am writing some code to RSA sign data. I have gotten this code to work successfully on Ubuntu (OpenSSL version is 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.7). The code takes the message, and produces the signed result with the private key, I can verify is correct using a separate program and the matching public key.

Under windows, the exact same code produces a different result, the signed data is different (And does not verify. I can't figure out why. I am using the OpenSSL distribution 'Win64OpenSSL-1_0_1j' from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html .

Here is the code:

```
const char * rsa_pri_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        "MII...L1t\n"
        "yC0...+zk\n"
        "c0...5Q\n"
        "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf( (void*)rsa_pri_key, -1 );
BIO_set_flags( bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL );

RSA* private_key = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL ) ;
if( !private_key )
{
    std::cout << "Key load failed" << std::endl;
}
BIO_free( bio ) ;


// Sign the data
signature = (unsigned char*) malloc(RSA_size(private_key));

RSA_sign(NID_md5, (unsigned char*) message, strlen(message), signature, &slen, private_key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be related to the char type on Linux and windows differing in whether they're signed or not. You're casting to (unsigned char *) which might be where the issue arises.

Comment: This prompted me to discover the real issue was with the encoding of the message on Linux Vs. Windows. Thanks.